# GWT mvp sample project: cannot call method of presenter

Tags: java, gwt

I am using the GWT mvp sample project to create my own mvp application.

I pretty much did what they did, i. e. defined a `Presenter` interface and then different presenter classes.

In their code, they are doing something like this in one of the `View` classes:

```
@UiHandler("loginButton")
void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
    if (presenter != null) {
        presenter.onLoginButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

The presenter is injected through this method:

```
public void setPresenter(IPresenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;

}
```

Well duh... turns out, I am unable to call the onLoginButtonClicked, since IPresenter is an interface. They do that in their code. How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a class that implements Presenter interface for this view.

Something like:

```
public class MyActivity extends AbstractActivity implements MyView.Presenter {}
```

Then you have a View class:

```
public interface MyView extends IsWidget {

    public interface Presenter {
        void onLoginButtonClicked();
    }

    void setPresenter(Presenter listener);
}
```

Finally, you will have an implementation of this view:

```
public class MyViewImpl extends Composite implements MyView {}
```

NB: I strongly recommend [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) pattern. It gives a good structure for any app with more than one view, and adds good history support.

Comment: Right, I need another interface (or class). Thanks man! Thanks also for the tipp on activities and places, but I am still trying to suss out the basics of mvp... gotta take it slow :)